# How to correctly develop, upload java library with dependencies to Oracle DB and call my Java function from PL\SQL?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

**I have:**

1. Oracle 19c
2. java 8 on its machine

**What i did:**

I write simple class with one method in Java 8.

```
package <mypackage>;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.networknt.schema.JsonSchema;
import com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory;
import com.networknt.schema.SpecVersion;
import com.networknt.schema.ValidationMessage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class <classname> {

    <some simple validation function>
}
```

I compile my project with maven and `maven-assembly-plugin` to build `.jar` file with dependencies.

I upload it with `loadtool`: `loadjava -f -r -v -synonym -oracleresolver -resolve -grant <user> -thin -user <credentials> <filename>.jar`

There were 0 errors during upload. All uploaded classes (including dependencies) have 'VALID' status in `dba_objects` table.

I write PL/SQL wrapper over my Java function.

```
create FUNCTION <funcname>(P_IN_BODY_TEXT CLOB, P_IN_BODY_SCHEMA_TEXT CLOB)
        RETURN VARCHAR2
    AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME '<packagename>.<classname>.<funcname>(java.sql.Clob, java.sql.Clob) return java.lang.String';
/
```

I use this function in my ORDS REST Service.

**When doing request to ORDS i am getting this exception:**

```
The request could not be processed because an error occurred whilst attempting to evaluate 
the SQL statement associated with this resource. 
Please check the SQL statement is correctly formed and executes without error. SQL Error Code: 29532, 
Error Message: ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ORA-06512: at <rest stacktrace that gives me nothing>
```

**Quiestion is:**

What is root of this problem? By `-synonym` flag tool creates synonyms for me, all classes is valid. Do i need some permisions to use java packages liike `java.sql` that in my class imports? I upload some others open sources java libraries into my Oracle, but they doesn't hava dependencies - is that the problem?

Comment: At a guess, I would say that Oracle's embedded JVM has no access to the JSON library that you are using. That's probably why you are getting `NoClassDefFoundError`. In any case, Oracle has extensive [JSON support](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/index.html). Is that not sufficient for your needs? If you want to go the Java route, then maybe this will help: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/oracle-and-plsql/9781430232070/loading_java_libraries_into_the_database.html

Comment: @Abra
My needs is validate request JSON bodies by [JSON Schemas](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html). Yes i can validate JSON with `JSON_ELEMENT_T` but its will be really tedious to validate complicated JSON compare to just write JSON Schema.

Comment: @Abra to your edit: I already compile fatjar with all dependencies inside, but i will give it a try to load dependencies seperatly. Thatnks for link.

Comment: Any reason you are not using JDeveloper?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen how does its suppos to help me?

Comment: @Abra seperate upload gives the same result. All classes valid, same error occured.

Comment: @lelacib940 Deploying Java code to Oracle is what JDeveloper is intended for.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen which is diong it via `loadjava` tool like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in `slf4j` library that throws this exception. `slf4j` was dependency of library that i used.
Didn't dig the problem, I just pick another labrary with less dependencies and its works.